# How to store an array of data in an array of objects in firestore using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

```
    saveUsernames(){
      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
      db.collection('users').where('user_id',"==", user.uid).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
          for(i=0; i<=this.usernames.length; i++){
          db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).update({
            name: this.name,
            bio: this.bio,
            usernamelist:[{Id:i, username: this.usernames[i]}]
          })}
        })
      }).then(() =>{
        this.$router.push({ name: "Profile" })
      })
```

I have an array of usernames stored in usernames[] that I want to store to my user docs. The index corresponds to the Id of each element in the Firestore doc 'users' in the element 'usernamelist' inside that element named 'username' at the corresponding Id value. How would I cycle through each element in the data array and update the corresponding element in firestore? I am getting an error saying 'i' is not defined.

Comment: Hi jeffrey Could you be more cleared pls !

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stack!

I am not sure what you are trying to do, however for sure, if you iterate over the array with index you should use `<` not `<=` like:

```
for(i=0; i<this.usernames.length; i++)
```

Otherwise, in last iteration you are out of index range. This is because index starts with `0`, so last index is array length - 1.

2nd thing is that I am not sure if this `update` inside loop will work as this is asynchronous  function ([reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#update)). I suggest to create whole field and than update it in one `update` statement.

I hope it will help!